# How to I coordinate a camera with the eyes of a model?

Tags: xna, performance, models

I am currently working on an FPS in XNA and I wanted to know how I would position the camera at the eyes of the model and whenever the model rotated or moved it's head (where the eyes are), the camera would move along with it. Also, whenever the player moves the camera (with their mouse) the model would turn it's head and eventually it's body.

I believe this would reduce the need for constant transformations and the planning of cutscenes by having an animation play and the camera follow that animation. It would also cut the need for transforming the model constantly when I add a future multiplayer.

I'm also open to any other ideas, so please, leave a comment letting me know what you think would be good and efficient.

Comment: every frame set camera pos, and direction the same than the bone placed on the head, done.

Comment: Considering also not rendering the head. That you can improve conditions and if the camera is always looking away from the head there is no reason to render it anyway as the player can't see it.

Comment: @Thijser, that makes sense, but what about multiplayer? I'd leave it for multiplayer, right? Why not get used to the same system instead of having to build two different ones? :/

Comment: You will most likely want to render other heads but not the player himself. I hope you are not planning on sending all the graphics live and instead just send player positions rather then their entire models anyway.

Comment: That makes sense, and I'm new to this stuff anyways, so I'm open to just about anything.