# How would I warp a mesh with code?

Tags: xna, 3d, graphics, camera

I recently asked a question about putting a camera at the head of a 3D human model [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79083/how-to-i-coordinate-a-camera-with-the-eyes-of-a-model) and it worked out rather well and whatnot, but there is still a problem that bothers me:

How would I contort/warp the mesh of the human model with code? I'd only really have to turn the head a bit using the mouse, and the rest can be animated (i.e. walking, moving arms, speaking, etc).

I was initially thinking about an animation for moving the head in a certain direction, and you would move the mouse and the animation would go along with the mouse movement until it reached the maximum angle (about 85 degrees) on either side of the model.

Is there a better way of doing this, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: So, you want to turn the model's head in different directions depending on user input?  Are you familiar with skeletal animation?  Sounds like you could just set the neck joint to the desired rotation and you'd be done.  (Or if you have multiple neck joints, distribute the rotation amongst them for a more natural-looking result.)